# Using VBA in Excel - Static variable not retained when Multipage object has change event (changing pages)

Tags: excel, vba, variables, static, userform

I am having trouble with losing static variables within an Excel user form.

I have been working on a routine for excel.  I am a (very) novice coder.

I am attempting to populate a cell range to an array. I have been able to do this without issue.

However, when I attempt to store the array as a *static * variable, the variable is not retained for as long as I want it to be.

I think the problem occurs when another page is selected in the multipage, the static variable is cleared.

Code is something like this:

---

```
Sub UserForm_Initialize ()

static myArray () as variant

dim myRange as range

set myRange = [namedrange]

myArray=myRange

msgbox myArray(0,0) 'this works fine

call OtherSub

end sub
```

---

```
sub OtherSub ()

msgbox myArray(0,0) 'this returns a blank

end sub
```

---

The first sub of code shows the array element just fine. The array element is blank in the second sub.

I have tried:

- Declaring the array as a public variable, but this returns an error (I think that variables within user forms are private by default and cannot be changed).
- using a very small variable (a simple string)
- writing code in a module before opening the user form (variable is not retained).

I am aware that I can just write data to a cell range, but this would defeat the purpose.  I was hoping to avoid multiple instances of reading large arrays from the worksheet.

Comment: This is a scope issue.  See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-scope-and-visibility)

Comment: Thanks Joseph.  I had read this section and I thought I had addressed this issue by declaring the array as a public variable.  This gave an error: "Compile error: Invalid attribute in sub or function."  I think this relates to variables in user forms being automatically private.  I'm not sure if there is a work around for this...

Comment: Declare your Array outside of your Sub UserForm_Initialize.  When declared inside the sub it is local only to that sub.  Using OPTION EXPLICIT would help by giving you an error that it hasn't been declared yet in the OherSub

Comment: Thanks Joseph.  My initial checks indicate that this is probably working now.  I will confirm when I have checked properly. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This might explain it a bit clearer.  Moving MyArray outside of the Procedure will set it's scope to a Module Level, making it usable through other subs within that module.  You will generally want to keep the scope of your variables to the lowest level required.  The other option would be to pass your variable as a parameter to your other procedure.

```
Option Explicit

Dim MyArray() As Variant            ' Private Module Level Scope
Public ExampleVariable As String    ' Public Module Level Scope (Not required, just showing an example.)

Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   
    Dim myRange As Range            ' Procedure Level Scope
    Set myRange = [namedrange]
    
    MyArray = myRange
    MsgBox MyArray(0, 0) 'this works fine

    Call OtherSub
End Sub

Sub OtherSub()
    MsgBox MyArray(0, 0) 'this returns a blank
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks again Joseph.  The problem I had is that I was getting errors when I attempted to declare the public variable within the UserForm_Initialize sub.  Now I have declared these within a module outside of the Init sub, it seems to be working fine.  When you mention passing the variable as a parameter do you mean with syntax such as: Call NewSub (myArray), where myArray would no longer need to be a module level variable?

Comment: @Mighty_Bear Public variables should be declared in Standard modules. The form's code behind file is private to the form, only to handle the various form/control events. You shouldn't have anything `Public` in the form's code file.

Comment: Thanks Kostas. Joseph and you have cleared this up for me nicely.  My code is now working as intended! :-)